# Can I configure and start TIme Machine from the commandLine

Tags: keyboard, backup

I have a problem with my MacBookPro, the left click button on (any) mouse and the trackpad doesnt respond to any clicks, so the only thing that works properly is the keybaord.

I havent been able to solve the issue so I am taking my labtop to an Apple store on Friday, but I fear they may need to send it away and may wipe the disk so Id really like a backup of the machine.

But although I have backups of my most immportant docs I have never used Time Machine and dont have a backup of the whole thing. So Id really like to do a backup but I cannot seem to configure anything in the Time Machine preferences with only the keyboard, is there a commandline equivalent that I can use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of OS 10.7, you can control Time Machine from the command line. The command line tool is called (and is called *with*) `tmutil`. Open up the Terminal, which is located in your `/Applications/Utilities` folder. It will be easy to get there if, From the Finder, you type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, which brings up a sheet where you can type the destination path to the Terminal (copy and paste this): `/Applications/Utilities`.

After the Terminal opens, and at the prompt, type `man tmutil`, which will get you the manual page for `tmutil` outlining all the commands and options available. It's quite extensive, and more than can be covered in a single answer, but examples might be:

> Turn on Time Machine backups:
>   `tmutil enable`
>
> Set the destination to be used as backup:
>   `tmutil setdestination...` (this has options that can be added to specify destination information and type)
>
> Start a full backup to a drive:
>   `tmutil startbackup -d /Volumes/Name_Of_Your_Backup_Disk`

You must carefully read this manual all the way through and understand the terminology before beginning. The manual is also available online at Apple's manpages reference area. You can read it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/tmutil.8.html), and there is a [good primer](http://simon.heimlicher.com/articles/2012/07/10/time-machine-inherit-backup-using-tmutil) on Simon Heimlicher's site with much better examples than what I've given above.

As with all command line tools, USE CAUTION. You will have to run most of these as root as well, which means that you're granting yourself power to do lots of potentially nasty things to your computer. In the case of `tmutil`, though you're unlikely to do much damage as you have to correctly specify a destination before it'll actually do anything. Probably the greatest hazard would be if you'd already set a destination you could accidentally erase it; since you have no destination, though, that's not going to happen.

Good luck getting your backup going and with getting your machine fixed!

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer, however Ive now found an easier way round by Gui problems by toggling to Mouse Keys (by pressing OPtion key 5 times) I can simulate a mouse click with Cntl-I so I'll probably configure TimeMachine with Gui after all.

Comment: Cool. Hope you get it squared away soon.